# Electron HTTPS for local file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Tried using electron to work with web speech API but it records no voice. It is probably due to the HTTPS connection requirement, but how would I show HTTPS if I am loading the app locally like 
 win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
?

I basically want to use webspeechapi on my local app but it does not seem to work. I think it is probably due to the requirement of having an https connection. How would i go about having it if i am using a simple main.js file?

Comment: can you be more specific? Paste some code examples, share any errors you are getting.

Comment: im sorry i think i framed my question wrong. I basically want to use webspeechapi on my local app but it does not seem to work. I think it is probably due to the requirement of having an https connection. How would i go about having it if i am using a simple main.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), and connect to your app via that, rather than at localhost.